# DownloadError in App Engine when requesting specific urls

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch, google-app-engine-python

I'm getting strange DownloadError while trying to request specific url using urlfetch.fetch

Here is the example code:

```
url = 'https://iiko.net:9900/api/0/auth/access_token'
try:
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url, deadline=50, validate_certificate=False)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        pass
 except DownloadError as er:
    logging.exception(er)
```

And here is the error:

```
Unable to fetch URL: https://iiko.net:9900/api/0/auth/access_token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~iappintheair/phil-dev.383038517236330514/handlers/api/test.py", line 18, in get
    result = urlfetch.fetch(url, deadline=50, validate_certificate=False)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 271, in fetch
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 414, in _get_fetch_result
    raise DownloadError("Unable to fetch URL: " + url + error_detail)
DownloadError: Unable to fetch URL: https://iiko.net:9900/api/0/auth/access_token
```

I'm sure that it's not connected with deadlines, because this code fails in a few seconds.

Possibly it's connected with broken ssl cerificate on this website, or GAE ip-addresses are blocked for some reason by this site, but I can't contact them right now.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yep, it does look like it's connected to iiko.net's broken SSL/TLS configuration -- even trying with a browser raises dire warnings...:-(  The `validate_certificate` arg doesn't seem to be doing anything much.  Per https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=validate_certificate&colspec=ID+Type+Component+Status+Stars+Summary+Language+Priority+Owner+Log&cells=tiles , there are many open issues around this -- you could star one or more, though it won't help you "right now"... dealing with broken HTTPS servers is *such* a pain!-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem was a broken SSL certificate, now everything works fine.
As a workaround we used proxy server, I know that it's not a perfect solution, but I have no idea how to fix it on app engine level.